# Get null or empty query set in django

Tags: django

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        key = self.request.GET['search_text']
        customer_list = customer_info.objects.all()
        # temp =
        for term in key.split():
            temp = temp | customer_list.filter(Q(fName__icontains=term)|Q(lName__icontains=term))
        return temp
```

How can I assign the value of temp to null query set of `customer_info` objects so that I could union temp with the filter list then return it. Basically, I am splitting the search box text and then filtering the table with each string in the list and combining the result initial result.

Comment: Note the recommended style in Python and Django is to name your model `CustomerInfo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an empty queryset with [`none()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#none):

```
MyModel.objects.none()
```

An alternative approach is to `or` the `Q()` objects together instead of querysets:

```
q = Q()
for term in key.split():
    q = q | Q(fName__icontains=term) | Q(lName__icontains=term)
return customer_info.objects.filter(q)
```